# Jump to page of PDF in iframe with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, iframe

I have a PDF in an iframe. If I load the `src` as `/pdf#page=4` the PDF will jump to page 4 when the iframe first loads, but I want to achieve this effect after the page loads via Javascript/jQuery.

I would like to be able to jump around pages using links on my page. My Javascript code is:

```
function pageView(num) {
    var src = $('#previewFrame').attr('src');

    str = src.substring( 0, src.indexOf( "page=" ) ); //Remove page=1 segment
    str = str+'page='+num; //Add new page=x segment

    $('#previewFrame').attr('src', str); //Set new iframe src

}
```

And the HTML:

```
<a onclick="pageView(1)">Page 1</a>
<a onclick="pageView(2)">Page 2</a>
<a onclick="pageView(3)">Page 3</a>
<a onclick="pageView(4)">Page 4</a>
<iframe src="/../pdf#page=1" width="100%" height="550px" id="previewFrame"></iframe>
```

This generates the new URL correctly (checked via printing the URL to console), but the PDF does not load the page. If I replace `str` with a regular URL it loads fine, so I know that Javascript is working - it is only when changing the PDF `#page=x` segment that nothing changes.

How can I force the PDF to jump to the right page? I would rather do this without reloading the actual PDF within the iframe again, but don't mind if this is necessary.

Comment: I can make code based on this work in firefox, but not chrome or edge ... using pdf.js to display the pdf your code works cross browser

Comment: @JaromandaX Hmm yes I had a feeling it might end up being a browser issue... I will look into pdf.js, thank you.